# Twenty fifteen - Theme background customization

Tags: theme-twenty-fifteen

I've been working on a website using the twenty fifteen theme because the layout is almost the same as the client's wants.

But my problem is how can I change the full size background of the page for every page...

It is a multipage actually and not a one page website

Any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: Don't shout please. Please properly format your title

Comment: Where does the full size background come from? There isn't one in the [theme demo here](https://wp-themes.com/twentyfifteen/). Did you mean the large image for the post, i.e. the boat?

Comment: No, I mean the background in the customize section..it gives me a full background..but the problem is I want to make a different background for every page

Answer (score 3):

Twenty Fifteen has a hook for you to modify the custom background theme_support arguments ([documentation for those arguments here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds)):

```
// Setup the WordPress core custom background feature.
add_theme_support( 'custom-background',
    apply_filters( 'twentyfifteen_custom_background_args',
        array(
            'default-color'      => $default_color,
            'default-attachment' => 'fixed',
) ) );
```

You can implement this filter in your child theme's functions.php, e.g.

```
function wpse_224240_custom_background_args($args) {
    $args['default-image'] = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/background.jpg';
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'twentyfifteen_custom_background_args',
            'wpse_224240_custom_background_args' );
```

and add any extra logic you need to change the image there. For example if you want a specific different image per post then you could store that in post metadata and only set the `'default-image'` if you have a different URL from metadata to use. If you wanted to pick a random one from a set you can do this here too, etc., either hard-coding the set or storing it as an option if you'd like it configurable.